# SSRS Pass main report parameter to subreport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a main report which accepts 4 parameters 
Begin Date:
End Date:
Group(multivalued parameter)
Type

```
Main Report: 
StudentName|Class|Group|Total 
AAAAAAAAAAA|2    | C   | 153
BBBBBBBBBBB|2    | C   | 164

SubReport:
Sci|Mat|Eng|Bio
71 |35 |47 |0
```

When I click on Total it should give me the subReport. Wile do so, I'm not able to pass all the main report parameters to the subreport.
Both the report uses parameterized stored procedures. Please how can i achive it.
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on why you are not able to pass all of the parameters to the sub-report?  From your example above, If you clicked on 153 in the total box, what parameters would you want to pass to the sub?